# Does Hibernate Search allow to integrate lucene collector?

Tags: hibernate, search, hibernate-search

We are using Hibernate Search to do the full text search in our application.
A customization field is tokenized into the lucene index. The customization field in the database actually contains values like 'material:iron,silver;color:red,blue'. How can I get faceted result like iron(7), silver(6), red(1), blue(9).

I did some research indicating that we can use Collector in lucene to achieve this. But I am not sure if Hibernate Search support Collector integration.